# How to save checkmark state in a UITableView for Core Data App in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I have implemented a list application using Core Data.What I wanted to do is add checkmarks so the user can click on a cell and a tick would show up to show it is completed.

I don't know how to save these checkmarks so when the app is closed and opened or restarted the check will still be there on the specific cell. Should I implement this with CoreData or NSUserDefaults? How would I go about implementing it using these?

Here is the code so far:

cellForRowAtIndex :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as UITableViewCell
    let item = Items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.item = task.valueForKey("item") as? String

    return cell
}
```

DidSelectRowAtIndex:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    let selectedRow:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    if selectedRow.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None {

        selectedRow.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

        selectedRow.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    } else {

        selectedRow.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

    } 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your core data entity needs a `completed` arrribute. When a task is completed, set it to true and save the object. Use the value of this attribute to determine whether a check mark should be added to a given row in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: okay i have now added an attribute called 'completed' in my core data entity and set it to boolean, let me get this straight do i set the completed tasks to true in the didSelectRowAtIndex method?

Comment: Yes. In that method you set it to true (or perhaps false if it is already true and you want to support a toggle functionality) and then save the object. In that method you can add the check mark and also in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can check completed and set the accessory view to check mark or none as appropriate

Comment: so something like ' selectedRow.setValue(true, forKey: "completed") ' would be used in the didSelectRow method? in the code '' if selectedRow.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None {} '' in my above code?

Comment: Not selectedRow, you use the row value from the indexPath to get the NSManagedObject from `listItems`

Comment: would it be possible for you to show a code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to track the completion status in your data model (The Core Data objects) not the cells.  Cells are re-used as you have found, also cells aren't persisted, so the checkmark state isn't saved.

I would use something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let taskObject=self.listItems[indexPath.row]
    var taskStatus = taskObject.valueForKey("completed") as? Bool ?? false

    taskObject.setValue(!taskStatus,forKey:"completed") // Toggle completed status

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Cannot save object: \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath,animated:false)

    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
}
```

Then, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can render the row appropriately:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("listCell") as! UITableViewCell
    let task = listItems[indexPath.row]
    let taskStatus = task.valueForKey("completed") as! Bool
    cell.textLabel?.text = task.valueForKey("task") as? String

    var accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    var tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    if (taskStatus) {
         accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
         tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }

    cell.accessoryType=accessoryType
    cell.tintColor = tintColor

    return cell
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time but i am getting 2 errors of ' type 'NSManagedObjects' has no subscription members' at lines 'let taskStatus = task["completed"] as! Bool' in 'CellForRow' and 'var taskStatus = taskObject["completed"] as! Bool' in 'DidSelect'?

Comment: Sorry.  I was typing from memory. You can use `valueForKey["completed"]` and `setValue(,forKey:)` but using Core Data is much easier if you get Xcode to generate the NSManagedObject subclasses for you.

Comment: so would i use `setValue(,forKey:)` in `didSelect` and `valueForKey` in `cellForRow`? sorry I'm new to core data and i was thinking of this a starter project to help me learn, if its easier would you be able to update your code with `valueForKey` and `setValue`?

Comment: You should initialise this value to `false` when you create a new task .  Which line through the nil exception?

Comment: its the `let taskStatus = task.valueForKey("completed") as! Bool` line in `CellForRow`

Comment: Ok.  Probably your old tasks don't have any value for completed.  As I said you should make sure this gets initialised to false when you create new tasks but I can edit the code to be more robust

Comment: When you create the new task object, `newTask.setValue(false,forKey:"completed")`

Comment: okay I've got it working now thanks a lot :) i initialised the value in the method where i create a new task and the only changes i needed to make to your code to get rid of some errors was in `cellForRow:` i changed `taskObject.valueForKey("completed")` to `task.valueForKey("completed")` and i added `()` to the end of `tintColor` thanks again.

Comment: What error do you get if you omit the () from tintColor?  Needing () doesn't make sense as you just want to set the `tintColor` property to the `tintColor` local variable

Comment: The () should be after greenColor() and clearColor(), then you don't need them after tintColor